# The closure of range of $T^*$ and the complement of kernel of T

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

In Hilbert space $H$, let T be bounded linear function from $H$ to $H$.

Also, the dimension of $H$ can be infinite.

> $\textbf{Exercise}$ $R (T) ^{\perp}=\ker(T^*)$ and $\ker(T)^\perp$$=\overline{R(T^*)}$

In Exercise, $T^*$ is bounded linear transformation on $H$ such that 
\begin{align*}
 (Tf,g)&=(f,T^*g)\\
\Vert T \Vert &=\Vert T^* \Vert\\
(T^*)^*&=T
\end{align*}

I showed that $R (T) ^{\perp}=\ker(T^*)$.
In infinite vector space, $R(T^*)$ may not be closed.
I want to know how to prove  $\ker(T)^\perp=\overline{R(T^*)}$ by using set inclusion.

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: In the usual parlance, a *linear functional* is an $\Bbb F$-linear map $H \to \Bbb F$, where $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb F = \Bbb C$;  are you sure that's what you want/mean here?  Or is $T:H \to H$ a bounded $\Bbb F$-linear *operator* instead?  Cheers!

Comment: Because if $T:H \to \Bbb F$, then $R(T) = \Bbb F$ unless $T =0$.

Comment: @Robert Lewis, Thank you. I missed that.

Comment: Glad to help out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume Robert Lewis's comment is correct, and you didn't mean "functional."

You already know $$R(T^*)^\perp = \ker((T^*)^*)=\ker(T)$$ Now take orthogonal complement of both sides, giving $$(R(T^*)^\perp)^\perp=\ker(T)^\perp$$
All that remains is to apply the result $(E^\perp)^\perp=\overline E$ which holds for any subspace $E$. If you're not familiar with this result, try to prove it from the definition of orthogonal complement.

Comment: I got it !!! Thank you. It's clear to me.